# Earth-like planet : the development of first civilisations

Tags: humans, earth-like, civilization

After building tectonic plates and today's continents shape of this earth-like planet, comes the time to put humans on it. On this planet, humans have expanded and traveled the same way *Homo erectus* and *Homo sapiens* did ; they are present on every continent of this world.

I know that agriculture was a big factor in the development of early civilisations, but I was wondering **what** other **factors are to be taken into account to spot the best areas for first (big) civilisations to thrive ?**

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A warm temperate climate with sufficient rain would be very helpful if not prerequisite. This would make it easier to find and or grow food and support a larger population.

The presence of beasts of burden would also be very helpful. Civilisations have arisen without them (e.g. the Maya), but the Maya were greatly hampered by their absence and food production occupied a huge proportion of the population – even greater than the high proportion in Europe.

Fertile coastal plains and rivers would also be very helpful. This would provide good quality farming land and waters for fishing as well as a means of communication via the rivers.

A large area of such land hundreds of square miles or more would be beneficial as resources might easily be quickly consumed in a smaller area and any developing civilisation would quickly be inhibited (e.g. Easter island).

Comment: This is pretty comprehensive.  An advantage that the big Eurasian civilizations had is that they were all in contact with one another so really useful innovations (domesticated animals, crops, bronze etc) could diffuse to all of them.

Answer (score 2):

A big chunk of ancient civilizations settled around water sources, especially rivers. This is because of its importance in agriculture as well as a good source of food. Rivers also served as great transportation with the use of boats.